# How can I set one div to take up the remaining space when the first div has 20vmin?

Tags: css

I have two `div`s, one `div` has a height of 20vmin. I want the other `div` to take up the remaining height.

I tried using things like 80vmin, but 80vmin is not always the remaining space.

I also tried using 80% for the second `div` but thats also not the remaining space.

Comment: `height: calc(100% - 20vmin)` ?

Comment: Is the parent/page set to 100% height.?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

Grids have a concept of “the remaining space” with `fr` units. So the way I would solve this is to style the parent of your divs as `display: grid`. Because your first div has a defined height, apply the size `auto` to the first grid row. Then apply the size `1fr` to the second grid row, and the second div will stretch to fill the row.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  margin: 0;
}

.d1 {
  border: 5px solid blue;
  height: 20vmin;
}

.d2 {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1"></div>
<div class="d2"></div>
```